# TreeMap not working with JSON

Tags: d3.js

I have a treemap which works fine with csv data, however, when I change the source to json, the tree does not appear.
Is the problem with the json format?

```
        d.company.forEach( function ( obj )
    {
            d.id = +obj.id;
            d.value1 = +obj.value1;
            d.value2 = +obj.value2;
    });
```

plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/PPLxOC6zxsnj6I3jCn4H?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `d3.csv` and `d3.tsv`, `d3.json` does **not** accept an *accessor* function. In your case, the accessor function is `cast`:

```
d3.json("data.json", cast, main)
```

So, instead of using an accessor function, remove `cast`:

```
d3.json("data.json", main)
```

And do whatever `cast` does with your data inside your `main` function.

Here is the API showing the differences between `d3.csv` and `d3.json`: https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md .